# How to get AST in C using eclipse CDT api?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I am new in using CDT api and I can't find any detailed documentation for using CDT. I have downloaded the CDT of version 8.4 and tried to use the packages in org.eclipse.cdt.core_5.7.0.201406111759 (such as org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast).For now I check the documentation in https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/eclipse-doc36/ and http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp(in CDT plug-in development guide), but both of them do not have specific explanation.

I will be very grateful if someone can help me!

Comment: is this question has to do some thing with java?

Comment: Vote-to-closer:  You claim an answer would be too broad.  OP is looking for specific guidance on how to use this tool to achieve a specific effect.  How is this different than many other questions of "how to accomplish X" using a specific tool?  Another experienced CDT user can likely help him out.  Your reason to close is not valid.

Comment: I just need some explanation about using CDT to manipulate AST and some example codes will help a lot I think. And this is exactly a problem about "how to accomplish X using a specific tool".